# Flurl & xUnit doesn't Catch Exception using await

Tags: c#, async-await, xunit, flurl

I'm setting up a consumer for a WebAPI and writing some unit tests.  The 'act' portion of my test is as follows:

```
var dta = await service.AuthenticateAsync(customerId, userName, password, machineId);           

try
{
    service.AuthenticateAsync(customerId, userName, password, machineId).Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    exUnauthorized = ex;
}
try
{
    httpTest.SimulateTimeout();
    await service.AuthenticateAsync(customerId, userName, password, machineId);
 }
 catch (AggregateException ex)
 {
     exTimeout = ex;
 }
```

I set up Flurl HttpTest as follows:

```
httpTest.RespondWithJson(auth)
                .RespondWith(status: (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

In order to get a first response of success and second of unauthorized.  As you can see later in the code I set up timeout to test that (if I set it up initially it seems to time out for all requests).

The first call succeeds.  The second call where I use `Wait()` in the try block works and catches the aggregate exception.  The second call where I use `await` does not catch the exception; it fails the unit test with the exception thrown by the method.

What am I missing?  Why doesn't the await call work right?

Comment: `await` [unwraps the exception](https://binary-studio.com/2014/06/04/5-things-you-should-know-about-asyncawait-in-c/), just catch the exception your method throws

Comment: Dang.. I hate it when I miss something really simple :).  Thank you! Make it an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Downvoter, I did Google for a while and didn't find anything, sorry.  What was the issue with the question that earned a down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` doesn't wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`, as it is intended for use in asynchronous code. `Wait()` and `Result` do wrap underlying exceptions in an `AggregateException`, as they are intended for use in parallel code.

Technically, it's not that `await` *unwraps* the exception; it just *doesn't wrap* it like `Wait`/`Result` do.